# wp_mail not working in acf/pre_save_post or acf/save_post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to send a confirmation email once the user has used the form I am creating via acf.

Below is the code I am using in a plugin, but somehow the wp_email is not sending an email. Not receiving it, nor did I receive an error.

```js
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

// check if this is to be a new post
if( $post_id != 'new_post' ) {

    return $post_id;

}
    // Create a new post
$post = array(
    'id' => $post_id,
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'post_title' => $_POST['acf']['_post_title'],
    'email' => $_POST['acf']['field_5d49dcb49a31f'],
    'bedrag' => $_POST['acf']['field_5d49dd749a321'],
    'periodiek' => $_POST['acf']['field_5d49de569a322'],
);

// // insert the post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post ); 

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

$name = get_field('post_title', $post_id);
$email = get_field('email', $post_id);
$body_text = get_field('email_tekst', 'option');

$to = $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'From: Some name <info@somedomain.com> <noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'>');
$subject = 'Bedankt voor uw donatie: ' . get_field('bedrag', $post_id) . ' ' . get_field('periodiek', $post_id);
$body = $body_text;

wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

// return the new ID
return $post_id;

}
add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post');
```

Save the form works, as I see data in the backend.
But I am just not receiving the email.

To make sure that emails are send, I am using a plugin (wp mail smtp).

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Somebody an idea? Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know what was going wrong.

I didn’t used the correct priority.

Now using the following code:

```js
function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

add_action('acf/save_post' , 'my_save_post', 15);
function my_save_post($post_id) {

    if( get_post_type($post_id) !== 'donations' ) {
        return;
    }

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

    $name = get_field('post_title', $post_id);
    $email = get_field('email', $post_id);
    $body_text = get_field('email_tekst', 'option');

    $to = $email;
    $headers = array('From: some name <some email> <noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'>');
    $subject = 'Bedankt voor uw donatie: ' . get_field('bedrag', $post_id) . ' ' . get_field('periodiek', $post_id);
    $message = $body_text;

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );

    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
}
```

The priority is now 15, so runs after the save was done.